# Client/server communication between a Java server and an Android phone

Tags: android, javabeans, data-transfer

I'm looking for the best way to implement data transfer to and from an Android application.

Here's the solution I'm currently considering:

- Data are transferred using JSON, beans are serialized/deserialized using GSON
- Each object that can be transferred provides a "toBean" method and a constructor that takes a bean (enforced with a "Transferable" interface)
- Before serialization I add additional info to the bean such as the response status, time etc.

Does this look like a reasonable solution? is there another pattern I could/should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing sounds reasonable, I would personally use SOAP/REST web service since it is Java to Java, but that is just a personal choice, the best choice would probably be determined by the details of your interactions with the server as well.